# onpaste event not fired on textarea for image data

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, copy-paste

I have a working page for `<textarea>` description with `<input type="file">` upload.  I added screenshot `onpaste` support to the `textarea` which works in Firefox 52 and should work in Chrome.

However, in IE `onpaste` won't fire with a `<textarea>` focused for non-text data.

HTML test page (IE only for brevity):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"/></head><body><form>
<script type="text/ecmascript">
function tb_pasted(e) {
   document.getElementById('txtTest').value += ' evtfired ';
   var s = "data: " + clipboardData.getData("Text") + "\n";
   var numFinished = 0; var numStarted = 0;
   for( var i=0; i<clipboardData.files.length; ++i ) {
      ++numStarted;
      var file = clipboardData.files[i];
      var fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = function () {
          var base64Data = fileReader.result
          s += " s:" + file.size + " d:" + fileReader.result.substring(10, 30) + "\n";
          ++numFinished;
      }
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
   }
   function alertWhenDone() { 
      if( numFinished >= numStarted ) alert(s);
      else setTimeout(alertWhenDone, 100);
   }
   alertWhenDone();
   return false;
}
</script>
nofire on image: <br/><textarea id="txtTest" onpaste="return tb_pasted(event);"></textarea>
<br/><br/>always fires: <br/><div id="divTest" contenteditable="true"
     style="background-color:yellow; width:100px; height:100px;"
     onpaste="return tb_pasted(event);"></div>
</form></body></html>
```

Is there some way I can get `onpaste` to fire **anyways** for "text only" fields regardless of content type or do I have to eradicate all `<textarea>` and text fields from this page?  I've read about using `<div/>` as text entry, which might work, but I'm hoping there's a better way.

**EDIT:** I tried returning `false` from `onbeforepaste` and that doesn't seem to help at all.  Below won't fire an onpaste event in IE for non-text:

```
Enter some text: 
<textarea id="txtTest"
          onbeforepaste="alert('before paste'); return false;"
          onpaste="alert('pasting'); return true;"
          ></textarea>
```

Comment: In IE clipboard access is also affected by the IE Security zone settings for the domain. Use the File>Properties menu to find out which IE security zone your test site is mapped to. expected Internet.

Comment: @RobParsons Thanks for that.  I think it is working for a `<div>` element though so I'm hoping it's not related to security settings.  (In my test I'm running an HTML file from a local hard-drive, I do get a warning about features I have to allow)

Comment: It sounds like you are using the edit mode of the browser... can you post more code or a jsfiddle please.

Comment: @RobParsons I've updated the question with a code-sample.  I thought before it would get too long, but I guess it's better than a long written description.

Comment: you should only use an input type="file" to select a file collection. It will accecpt a paste command for files clipboarddata collection.... pasting files clipboarddata into a textarea or textinput element is converted to text, not a files collection.

Comment: There is an `onpaste` event which applies to `<textarea>`, `<input type="text">` and `<div>` (among others).  On `<div>` it supplies `files` data in all 3 browsers.  Is there a reason I can't or shouldn't use it?  Note: pasting files into a text field in IE doesn't do any conversion, the event simply doesn't fire and the data is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Aha!!! `onbeforepaste` event is built for just this problem.

You'd think it was as simple as returning `false` from `onbeforepaste` for a `<textarea>` but that doesn't seem to make the `onpaste` event fire.

However if you combine `return false` with `.focus()` on a non-text element (like `<div>`):

```
 nofire on image: <br/>
 <textarea id="txtTest" 
     onpaste="return tb_pasted(event);"
                                                fix="*** \/ ***"
     onbeforepaste="document.getElementById('divTest').focus();  return false;"
                                                fix="*** /\ ***"
     ></textarea><br/><br/>
 always fires: <br/>
 <div id="divTest" contenteditable="true"
     style="background-color:yellow; width:100px; height:100px;"
     onpaste="return tb_pasted(event);"></div>
```

Then in seems to work even in IE.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<style type="text/css">
html,body{
    margin:0px;padding:0px;height:100%; background-color:black;
}
#divtoolbar{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;left:0;width:100%;
}
#divContent{

}
#preview{

}
img.obj{
    max-width:320px;
}
img.obj.fullscreen{
    max-width:none;width:auto;height:auto;margin:auto;overflow:visible!important;
}
ul{
    padding:0px;list-style:none;background-color:black;
}
*:hover{
    outline:red dotted thick;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleFullScreen(evt) {
var el=evt.target;
  if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
      !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement ) {  // current working methods
    el.className='obj fullscreen'; 
    el.oncontextmenu=function(){return false;}
    if (el.requestFullscreen) {
      el.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (el.msRequestFullscreen) {
      el.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (el.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      el.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (el.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      el.webkitRequestFullscreen(el.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    el.className='obj';
    el.oncontextmenu=null;
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }
  }
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.preventDefault();
}

function handleFiles(files) {
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    var imageType = /image.*/;

    if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
      continue;
    }

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var el= document.createElement('li');
    img.classList.add("obj");
    img.file = file;
    img.addEventListener('dblclick',toggleFullScreen,false);
    el.appendChild(img)
    preview.appendChild(el); // Assuming that "preview" is a the div output where the content will be displayed.
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(aImg) { return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result;aImg.scrollIntoView(true); }; })(img);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
</script>
<title>filereader</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="divtoolbar">
<input type="file" name="filselect" id="filselect" multiple accept="image/*,audio/*,video/*" style="width:100%" onchange="handleFiles(this.files);"/>
</div>
<div id="divContent">
<ul id="preview"></ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What does full-screen have to do with this?  As I stated earlier, I've already got basic file upload working on this page.  My whole goal is for a user typing into a text field to be able to `Ctrl-V` or `right-click->Paste` a screenshot rather than opening an image editor, saving a file, clicking `browse...` finding the file etc.

Comment: Its in the file api test page that I had handy. Your original question and post showed that you were using an <textarea> element. not a file input element.

Comment: Yes, that's correct I'm using a `textarea` to create a "rich text" control where one type of data I want to accept paste for is file data (or a file descriptor).  Think of an email form with `textarea` message body where onpaste files turn into an "extra" paperclip nearby.  The code above is just a simple proof of concept example.